# Problema de trigonometría

Tags: javascript, canvas

estoy haciendo un editor royo canvas pero con HTML, todo va perfecto pero me encuentro con un problema de trigonometría que no consigo sacar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Según la imagen, tengo un div de 200px por 200px ubicada en la posición 0, 0 (esta puede ser otra posición pero en este caso es 0,0).

La roto 10deg hacia la derecha o izk y acto seguido agrando el height a 302px. Después este se desplaza hacia el lado opuesto cuando debería mantenerse en la misma posición.

El problema es que debo calcular la diferencia entre el centro girado y aumentado respecto al centro no girado para obtener la diferencia y restarlo para que quede en la misma ubicación.

Actualmente uso una formular para hacer justo lo contrario, que es obtener X2, Y2 y X1, Y1 teniendo la rotación y el punto central.

```
const center = { x: layer.size.width / 2, y: layer.size.height / 2 };
const rotate = this.getAbsoluteRotation(layer) * Math.PI / 180;

return {
  x: center.x - center.x * Math.abs(Math.cos(rotate)) - center.y * Math.abs(Math.sin(rotate)),
  y: center.y - center.x * Math.abs(Math.sin(rotate)) - center.y * Math.abs(Math.cos(rotate))
};
```

Entiendo que necesito la inversa de esta formula.

Gracias ;)

Comment: Dices *Después este se desplaza hacia el lado opuesto cuando debería mantenerse en la misma posición* No lo entiendo. ¿Que quieres que se quede en la misma posición?El centro del div? la esquina izquierda arriba?

Comment: SergioCaballero aun necesitas ayuda?

Comment: tienes que hacer una rotacion de matrices

Comment: Gracias @x-rw me he informado y si con matrices se soluciona el problema. :D